# python and json UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, json, utf-8, scrapy

I am currently facing some issues about encoding.
As I am French, I frequently use characters like `é` or `è`.

I am trying to figure out why they are not displayed in a JSON file I created automatically with `scrapy`...

Here is my python code :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy


class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pokespider'
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.pokepedia.fr/Liste_des_Pok%C3%A9mon_par_apport_en_EV"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for poke in response.css('table.tableaustandard.sortable tr')[1:]:
            num = poke.css('td ::text').extract_first()
            nom = poke.css('td:nth-child(3) a ::text').extract_first()

            yield {'numero': int(num), 'nom': nom}
```

Then, after typing the `scrapy` command, the code produces a JSON file. Here are its first lines :

```json
[
{"numero": 1, "nom": "Bulbizarre"},
{"numero": 2, "nom": "Herbizarre"},
{"numero": 3, "nom": "Florizarre"},
{"numero": 4, "nom": "Salam\u00e8che"},
...
]
```

*(Yes, these are French Pokémon names.)*

So, I would like to get rid of this `\u00e8` character, it should be an `è`...
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance, and I hope my English is not too poor :)

Comment: The function you shared yields the `nom` value, but you haven't shared how you're writing the result to a json file. If you print `"Salam\u00e8che"` from Python, you'll find that it correctly encodes to the character you need, but you probably need to encode the string before writing it to the json file, which should be written as a text file with the appropriate encoding, or a bytes file.

Comment: The JSON seems fine. The `è` is correctly escaped as you see the code point [here](https://unicode-table.com/fr/00E8/). Character escaping is explained in the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (2.5 Strings). Any system should have no problem to process that JSON. Why would you want to change it if I guess the JSON will be used by a system and not a human?

Comment: In case you think it affects the result, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is a declaration of the encoding of the *source file* and UTF-8 is the default for Python 3.  It has no affect in reading or writing files.  If you had non-ASCII chracters in the *source file itself* and the source was *not* saved in UTF-8, then the source declaration matters.

Comment: @Grismar It's automatically generated with a `scrapy` command so I do not have the control on how it's done...

@HernánAlarcón I know the JSON file is not used by a human but, it's easier for me to read while I am developing. It's the first time I use such files so, I prefer being aware of what I can do, and what I cannot.

@MarkTolonen Hehe, I knew it wouldn't change anything. I just got used to writing this line, because as you noticed, I don't quite like ASCII encoding haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING) option: here in custom_settings.

```
import scrapy
  
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pokespider'
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.pokepedia.fr/Liste_des_Pok%C3%A9mon_par_apport_en_EV"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for poke in response.css('table.tableaustandard.sortable tr')[1:]:
            num = poke.css('td ::text').extract_first()
            nom = poke.css('td:nth-child(3) a ::text').extract_first()

            yield {'numero': int(num), 'nom': nom}

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items_json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(BlogSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Happy to help. please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)